# Rolle's Theorem in proving exactly one real zero

Tags: roots, rolles-theorem

The question asks to use the Rolle's Theorem to prove $f(x)=(x-8)^3$ has only one real zero.

I have already used IVT to prove that there is a zero, but I'm stumped on how to use the Rolle's Theorem to prove there is only one zero, because all other methods I have seen for similar problems employ the fact that the derivative never equals zero, so there is no $a$ and $b$ where $f(a)=f(b)$ using the Rolle's Theorem. But the derivative of this equation does equal zero .. at $x=8$ ..

Comment: Well, you can say that if $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\ne 8$ then (without loss of generality assume $x_0>8$) the derivative vanishes at some point in the interval $(8, x_0)$, which is a contradiction because $8$ is clearly the only zero of $f'$. But to be honest, the question is really weird, because it is absolutely obvious that $8$ is the only zero of $f$, just as it is obvious that this is the only zero of $f'$.

Comment: Sounds like something has been lost in the translation. Here's the proof: if $x=8$ then $x-8=0$ so $(x-8)^3=0$. If $x \ne 8$ then $x-8 \ne 0$ so $(x-8)^3 \ne 0$.

Comment: Rolle's theorem says that $f(a) = 0$ and $f(b) = 0$ there exists a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f$ has at least two distinct roots. Call these $p_1$ and $p_2$. So $0=f(p_1)$ and $0=f(p_2)$. Then at some point $c$ (where $p_1<c<p_2$) we see $f'(c)=3(c-8)^2$ is zero. This is from Rolle's theorem.

Hence $c=8$. It follows that $p_1<8$ and $p_2>8$. But, for $x<8$ we see $(x-8)^3$ is negative, so $f(p_1)=0$ and $p_1<8$ is absurd. And (if $x>8$) $f(x)>0$ so $f(p_2)=0$ and and $p_2>8$ is absurd.

It follows that $f(x)$ can't have two (or more) real roots. The only other possible choice (that can create a problem for us) is if $f$ has zero real roots. However this is absurd as $f(8)=(8-8)^3$ is zero.

Comment: This argument doesn't really need Rolle's theorem, though.  You could skip that part and just argue "$f(p)=0$ and $p<8$ is absurd, $f(p)=0$ and $p>8$ is absurd, and $f(8)=0$."

Comment: Yes, that's fair & I'm sorry. So may I ask what was the person who posted the question expecting? I just assumed (as the user was mentioning IVT) we would be allowed to use basic facts of polynomials (such as polynomials of the form (x-k)^2 are always non-negative) - that is my view point, anyway.

Comment: No need for an apology.  I agree the question is kind of ridiculous.  I've been struggling to find a non-superfluous use of Rolle's theorem to do this problem and I'm not sure there is one.

Answer (score 0):

### BACKGROUND :

I think you are looking at it the wrong way.

Rolle theorem talks about $F(x)$ & makes claims about a root of $F'(x)$.
Here we want to make claims about a root of $f(x)$ , hence $F'(x)=f(x)$ & we will have to figure out what $F(x)$ is.

### Proof of 1 root :

It is easy to see that $F(x)=\frac{(x-8)^4}{4}+c_1$ will work.

Let $a=8-c_2$ & $b=8+c_2$

When we check $F(a)=F(8-c_2)$ & $F(b)=F(8+c_2)$ , we will get Equality.
$F(a)=F(8-c_2)=\frac{(8-c_2-8)^4}{4}+c_1=c_2^4/4+c_1=Y$
$F(b)=F(8+c_2)=\frac{(8+c_2-8)^4}{4}+c_1=c_2^4/4+c_1=Y$

Hence $F'(x)=f(x)$ must have a root between $a=8-c_2$ & $b=8+c_2$

### Proof of that 2 roots can not occur :

We then want to show that there can be no other root.

Let there be some $x$ value between $a=8-c_2$ & $b=8+c_2$ , that is , $x=8 \pm c_3$ , which makes $F(x)=F(8 \pm c_3)$ Equalize with the values at $F(a)$ & $F(b)$ , which will then give 2 roots for $F'(x)=f(x)$ within those 2 intervals , by Rolle theorem.

We can easily see that
$F(a) = F(8-c_2) = c_2^4/4+c_1 = Y$
$F(8 \pm c_3) = (8 \pm c_3-8)^4/4+c_1 = c_3^4/4+c_1 = Y$
$F(b) = F(8+c_2) = c_2^4/4+c_1 = Y$
will have no DISTINCT Positive Solution for $c_3$
[[ $ c_2^4/4+c1 = Y = c_3^4/4+c1$ will make $c_2 = c_3$ due to monotonicity within Positive range ]]
Thus there is no other interval & no other root.

### Summary :

Proof with other words , we will have this outline :
There are no three Points where we have Same value for $F(x)$.
Hence , there are no 2 intervals where the ENDPOINTS have Same value for $F(x)$.
Hence , there are no 2 intervals where Rolle theorem can claim $F'(x)=f(x)$ has roots.
Hence , there is only one interval where Rolle theorem can claim $F'(x)=f(x)$ has root.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this problem is certainly ridiculous, as comments have pointed out.  However, let's make lemonade from lemons and turn this into a challenge:  Prove that $f(x)=(x-8)^3$ has a unique root without solving any equations.

We slept through the equation solving part of Sister Agnes’s algebra course.  All we remember is how to substitute specific values into functions.

##### Proof

We'll go a step further and prove that every polynomial of the form $f(x)=a(x-8)^n$ for $n\geq 1$, $a\neq 0$ has a unique root at $x=8$.

We prove this by induction on $n$.  In the case $n=1$, we have $f’(x)=a\neq 0$, so by Rolle’s theorem we must have $f(c)\neq f(d)$ for all $c\neq d$.  In particular, substitution shows $x=8$ is a root, and hence the only root, of $f(x)$.

Suppose we have proved the theorem for $n=k$.  Then if $f(x)=a(x-b)^{k+1}$, we have $f'(x)=(k+1)a(x-b)^k$, so by our inductive assumption, $f'(x)$ has a unique root at $x=8$.

We claim this means $f(x)$ has a unique root at $x=8$ as well.  Otherwise, (since by substitution $x=8$ is indeed a root), if $r>8$ is another root, then by Rolle’s theorem there is a root for $f’(x)$ strictly between $r$ and $8$, contradicting uniqueness of the root for $f’(x)$.

Arguing similarly for $r<8$, we see $x=8$ is the unique root for $f(x)$.